# how to apply z-index for 3 div's

Tags: html, css

I have three div's on parent div i added one line using`: before` pseudo-class,
my question is I want to hide that line on blue color div and the line should come above red color div.i tried using z-index but not getting.
Can anyone suggest me where I have to add `z-index`?
below is my code

```css
.timeline-row {
 position: relative;
    display: flex;
    padding: 100px 0 0;
}
.timeline--seperator {
 background: red;
 position: relative;
 z-index: -1;
}
.timeline--icon {
 position: relative;
    background: blue;
    margin-left: 14px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(112, 128, 175, 0.09);
}
.is-circle {
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.is-square {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.timeline--seperator i {
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
.timeline--content h2 {
 font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
.timeline--content h3 {
    padding: 8px 0 15px;
 font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #8dd8ea;
}
.timeline--content p {
    font-size: medium;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #5f5f5f;
}
.timeline-wrap {
 position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 80px;
}

.timeline-row .timeline--content {
    width: 45%;
}
.timeline-row:nth-child(even) .timeline--seperator .timeline--icon { float: left; }
.timeline-row:nth-child(odd) .timeline--seperator .timeline--icon { float: right; }

.timeline-row:nth-child(even) > .timeline--seperator {
 order: 2;
}
.timeline-row:nth-child(even) > .timeline--content {
 text-align: right;
}
.timeline-row:nth-child(odd)  > .timeline--content {
 order: 1;
 text-align: left;
}
.timeline-wrap:after {
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 4px;
    height: 80%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.is-end {
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
.is-start {
 justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-wrap">
 <div class="timeline-row is-end">
  <div class="timeline--seperator">
   <div class="timeline--icon is-circle">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-4x"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline--content">
   <h2>RESEARCH & ANALYTICS</h2>
   <h3>DISCOVER</h3>
   <p> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essenum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedtially unchanged a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline-row is-start">
  <div class="timeline--seperator">
   <div class="timeline--icon is-circle">
    <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-4x"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline--content">
   <h2>TACTICAL PLAN</h2>
   <h3>IDEATION</h3>
   <p> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchanged a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This problem is easy solved by adding to z-index to the element you want to force. Just keep in mind that you can't set elements behind an object (with the exception of z-index -1). When multiplay stack logic is required and you don't mind using some extra cpu usage you can set opacity: 0.1. To all elements involve to get a stacking logic on the z-index. More information you can find here:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove "z-index" values on everything but add it only on ".timeline--icon"

```css
.timeline-row {
 position: relative;
    display: flex;
    padding: 100px 0 0;
}
.timeline--seperator {
 background: red;
 position: relative;
}
.timeline--icon {
 position: relative;
    background: blue;
    margin-left: 14px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(112, 128, 175, 0.09);
    z-index: 1;
}
.is-circle {
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.is-square {
    border-radius: 0;
}
.timeline--seperator i {
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
.timeline--content h2 {
 font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
.timeline--content h3 {
    padding: 8px 0 15px;
 font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #8dd8ea;
}
.timeline--content p {
    font-size: medium;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #5f5f5f;
}
.timeline-wrap {
 position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 80px;
}

.timeline-row .timeline--content {
    width: 45%;
}
.timeline-row:nth-child(even) .timeline--seperator .timeline--icon { float: left; }
.timeline-row:nth-child(odd) .timeline--seperator .timeline--icon { float: right; }

.timeline-row:nth-child(even) > .timeline--seperator {
 order: 2;
}
.timeline-row:nth-child(even) > .timeline--content {
 text-align: right;
}
.timeline-row:nth-child(odd)  > .timeline--content {
 order: 1;
 text-align: left;
}
.timeline-wrap:after {
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 4px;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.is-end {
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
.is-start {
 justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-wrap">
 <div class="timeline-row is-end">
  <div class="timeline--seperator">
   <div class="timeline--icon is-circle">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-4x"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline--content">
   <h2>RESEARCH & ANALYTICS</h2>
   <h3>DISCOVER</h3>
   <p> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essenum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchangedtially unchanged a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="timeline-row is-start">
  <div class="timeline--seperator">
   <div class="timeline--icon is-circle">
    <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-4x"></i>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline--content">
   <h2>TACTICAL PLAN</h2>
   <h3>IDEATION</h3>
   <p> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's unknown printer, remaining essentially unchanged a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```